# how to recover an element of a String

Tags: java, string

I have a string of the form:

```
str = "word1_word2_word3_word4_word5"
```

and I want to retrieve each keyword in a separate variable with the help of `"_"` how separator.

example: `str = "hello_how_are_you_?"`

```
for str1=hello, str2=how, str3=are, str4=you and str4=?
```

thank for your help and sorry for my school english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "hello_how_are_you_?"
String[] words = str.split("_");
```

Output:

```
words[0]; // hello
words[1]; // how
words[2]; // are
words[3]; // you
words[4]; // ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
String str = "hello_how_are_you_?";
String item[]=str.split("_")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use split for it.

```
 /* String to split. */
  String str = "one-two-three";
  String[] temp;

  /* delimiter */
  String delimiter = "-";
  /* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
  temp = str.split(delimiter);
  /* print substrings */
  for(int i =0; i < temp.length ; i++)
    System.out.println(temp[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String phrase = "hello_how_are_you_?";
String[] tokens = phrase.split("_");

for( String str: tokens)
     System.out.println(str);
```

This code will print this on the screen:

```
hello
how
are
you
?
```

**Anyway, if you are trying to make something Paraclete there should be a better way to do it then saving data in strings like that.**

Here is a tutorial in case you need something more complex then split by a single character: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str="hello_how_are_you_?";
    String[] strSplit=str.split("_");
```